# vb.net adding large sum on variable integer

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I created a queuing system which would display multiple counters and the queue number of the customer and their service group but when I update them, all data looks like the first counter. My update function is refreshed on timer tick so every 1 second it updates the information.

```vb
Public Sub updatecountera()
    openconnect()
    SQLi = "SELECT  `counter`,  `logconcern`, `logcustcurr`  FROM `access` WHERE  logstatus= 1 and counter=1 "
    SqlRun()
    If myData.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        countera.Text = "avail"
        counteracust.Text = "avail"
        counteraservice.Text = "avail"
    Else
        countera.Text = myData.Rows(0)(0)
        counteracust.Text = myData.Rows(0)(1)
        counteraservice.Text = myData.Rows(0)(2)
    End If
    closeConnect()
End Sub

Public Sub updatecounterb()
    openconnect()
    SQLi = "SELECT   `logconcern`, `logcustcurr`  FROM `access` WHERE  logstatus= 1 and counter=2 "
    SqlRun()
    If myData1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        counterb.Text = "avail"
        counterbcust.Text = "avail"
        counterbservice.Text = "avail"
    Else
        counterb.Text = myData1.Rows(0)(0)
        counterbcust.Text = myData1.Rows(0)(1)
        counterbservice.Text = myData1.Rows(0)(2)
    End If
    closeConnect()
End Sub
```

Every timer tick only the information of countera shows on all counter (counterb, counterc). When I try to include `mydata.clear()`, it shows an error of "no data row position". How can I get all the counters to update information without compressing all info in 1 sql statement and selecting per data row since it is very messy to do that?

## Edited to add SqlRun() method

yes i was missing 'counter' i added it on my counterb but it still shows identical information here is my sqlrun ():

```
Public Sub SqlRun()
    'transfer sql connections 
    SQL = SQLi 
    myCommand.Connection = conn
    myCommand.CommandText = SQL
    'execute adapter commands
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
    myAdapter.Fill(myData)
    myAdapter.Fill(myData1)
    myAdapter.Fill(mydata2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you're missing some code in updatecounterb as your SQL statement is only bringing back 2 columns not 3.  This might be causing your problem as, if MyData1 is global, then it may still have the values from upatecountera in it.

Comment: If you post the contents of your SqlRun method that would be helpful but I suspect just updating the SQL in updatecounterb to SQLi = "SELECT  `counter`,  `logconcern`, `logcustcurr`  FROM `access` WHERE  logstatus= 1 and counter=2 " will fix your problem

Comment: yes i was missing  'counter'   i added it on my counterb but it still shows identical information  here is my  sqlrun ()
 Public Sub SqlRun()
        'transfer sql connections
        SQL = SQLi
        myCommand.Connection = conn
        myCommand.CommandText = SQL
        'execute adapter commands
        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        myAdapter.Fill(myData)
        myAdapter.Fill(myData1)
        myAdapter.Fill(mydata2)
    End Sub